# NextJS SSR for child component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using next js so I can get SSR for a page rendered by this component. The problem is that I have a component called  which is rendered by by iterating through results from the API. The issue is that the content rendered from this component is not appearing on the DOM. How can I make get the content in  to appear on the DOM?

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from 'theme-ui';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import EntryComponent from 'src/components/hiphopleage/entry.component';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { IPlaylist, IPlaylistItem, IProjectTrack } from 'src/_models/music.model';
import { uniqueId } from "lodash";
import { IPlayerItem } from 'src/_models/player.model';

const ViewLeagueComponent = (props) => {
   const [League, setLeague] = useState<IPlaylist>();
   const [Tracks, setTracks] = useState<IPlaylistItem[]>();
   const { PlayerState, dispatchPlayer } = useContext(PlayerContext);

   useEffect(() => {
     if (props.xleague.data) {
        setLeague(props.xleague.data.playlists[0]);
        setTracks(props.xleague.data.playlistSongs);
     }
   }, [props])


   return (
    <div sx={{ variant: "center", placeItems: "start center" }} className="col-12">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-10 py-3">
            {Tracks && Tracks.map((x: IPlaylistItem, i: number) => <EntryComponent entry={x} index={i} key={uniqueId()} />)}
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default ViewLeagueComponent;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
const league = await fetch(`${API_URL}/music/playlists?category=league`);
const xleague = await league.json();

return {
    props: {
        xleague
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is not a page component (in /pages).

getServerSideProps, getStaticProps and getStaticPaths can only be used on the page components themselves, not normal components.